# Looks like I totally don't understand how python nose --match parameter works

Tags: python, testing, nose

By default --match parameter has value `'(?:^|[b_./-])[Tt]est'` which is fine (wait, no, I don't understand what that means). But if I want to run only test functions which start with a prefix `'.*test_post_object_.*'` (it is not a correct reg expression?), nose does not find anything and runs zero tests. Suppose I run nose in the same directory, where methods exist, and I know about -w parameter.

ps: And I could not find anything about nose testMatch, which is mentioned in the manual. This is so weird...

**psps: I found an ugly workaround, but at least it works:**

```
nosetests --collect-only -v 2>&1 | grep -e test_function_prefix | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/(.*//g' | sed 's/^.*://g' | while read test; do nosetests $test; done
```